# log into ec2 using SSH but sudo prompts for password

Tags: sudo

Have an EC2 instance.  Connect via ssh.  Can navigate through directories.

When I try to use a sudo command, I am prompted for a password.

`ubuntu@ec2-ip-address:/etc$ sudo su root

[sudo] password for ubuntu:`

I haven't ever set a password.  That is what SSH is for.  How do I change to the root user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do any of:

- set a password for your user
- set a password for root and use `su`
- change the sudoers file to allow passwordless sudo

Comment: 1)  change sudoers file - can't access, permission denied; can't chmod because a password is required.  2)  how can I set a password for user or root?

Comment: Presumably you're using an AMI provided by Amazon? It should have a default password for that user.

Comment: Sorry still struggling...  According to a few articles, the Amazon Ubuntu AMIs don't have passwords for user ubuntu -> http://superuser.com/questions/456885/ec2-ubuntu-ami-ssh-password-default-without-key

Comment: @ChristopherIckes This would be a question for the folks who provided the AMI. You must have either a root password (usable with `su`) or a user password (usable with `sudo`) in order to switch to root...

Comment: The AMI was errantly switched from an Amazon AMI to a 3rd party.  Switched back to Amazon AMI and issue is solved.